# script not terminating immediately 

Tags: php

I have a script that lets the user download files (stored in a blob field after doing a bin2hex() )

```
function hex2bin($h){ ... }
// code to get $filecontent,$filesize,$uploadname from database
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Length: $filesize");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$uploadname.'"');
echo hex2bin($filecontent);
```

everything is working fine, except the browser is taking 3 to 4 seconds after 
downloading the file to finally terminate the http session.

Any clue whats causing that.

thanks.
Pari

Comment: Can you check the content-length is coming out correctly

Comment: Have you tried sending the Connection: close header ?

Comment: Thanks Greg & svens

turns out i was doing a ob_start("ob_gzhandler") in one of the include files, which is causing the delay.
I turned it off and the download script is working fine now.

thanks for the help folks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was an ob_start("ob_gzhandler")
in one of the include files. Removing it solved the issue.

thanks everyone.
Pari

Answer (score 0):

Probably the "code to get $filecontent,$filesize,$uploadname from database" is the problem. Show it